# Pre-loader Image at page load issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am sorry for asking a very minor thing but I feel a bit helpless in this one. I have integrated a pre-loader image at my page load in a very simple way

[This is my Page link](http://104.238.102.6/~zerobytes/blue_lizard_audio/index.php/search?sort_key=1&term=a&zip=&active_nav_tab=1&category=&MIN_VAL=0&MAX_VAL=15000&radius=)

HTML: (Div for loading Pre-loader image)

```
 <div class="se-pre-con"></div>
```

Jquery to trigger the pre-loader on page load

```
  $(window).load(function() {
      // Animate loader off screen
      $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut();
  });
```

A bit of Styling . CSS

```
 <style>
.no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('http://www.rybena.com.br:8080/RybenaRepository/resource/img/loading.gif') center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

**Problem**
When Page loads, it splashes before the Pre-loader image one time and then loads after the pre-loader image complete its effect. Theoretically, pre-loader should display before page load. I hope anyone of you can figure out where and what I did wrong?

Regards

Comment: Tell the image in the css to display:none;

Comment: Thanks @ Andrew for replying so fast, this trick did improve my page load speed but now i can't see pre-loader at all. I placed display:none in Class .se-pre-con which is the div of my preloader. I have another question, if you don't mine me asking, Can I show the same pre-loader on page unload instead of showing at load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your HTML isn't well formatted on the link you provided:

What I would do is make sure the HTML page has a structure similar to this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="se-pre-con"></div>
        <div class="site-content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And inside your script tag have the following method:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    $(".site-content").show(); //or fadeIn (what ever suits your needs)
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut();
 });
```

And in your css make sure you set

```
.site-content{     
    display: none;
 }
```

**EDIT**: (To answer your question in comment- call loader at any time)

I would probably create a function like this:

```
function toggleLoader(show){
     if(show == true){
        $(".se-pre-con").show();
        $(".site-content").fadeOut();
     }
     else{
        $(".site-content").show();
        $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut();

     }
}
```

Then on **window load** you would call: toggleLoader(false),

When you make a **request** call: toggleLoader(true),

And when you receive a **response** call: toggleLoader(false).

Comment: This makes sense @ EaziLuizi but rather showing site content before pre-loader fade out Can I display site content after pre-loader fadeout?

Comment: Yeah of course, but i wouldn't use "fadeIn" then , rather display immediately with "show"

Comment: Thank you sir, don't mind me asking stupid question as I am a slow learner. Can I show a pre-loader image on both page load and unload. Currently page load displays the pre-loader but when the request is sent like search for new credentials it takes a bit time. How can I display the same pre-loader image immediately after the request is sent

Comment: Glad it helped, Have a look at my edited answer, should give you a good base to work on just make changes according to your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

page content is also visible on page load along with loader element so there no any sequence which content load first, but you can manger by following code, Suppose you have two div, one `pre-loader` div another site `container` div

```
<body>
     <div class="se-pre-con"></div>
     <div id="container" style="display: none;">
         <!-- site content here -->
     </div>
</body>
```

in `container` div add `display: none` style so site content cant't blink on page load.. and when page load then you can `show` container div, see below code

```
$(window).load(function() {
      // Animate loader off screen
      $("#container").show();
      $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just gone thru your page link and noticed that `display:none;` was added to `.se-pre-con` as shown below. Please remove the `display:none;` property. It works buddy!

```css
.se-pre-con {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('http://www.rybena.com.br:8080/RybenaRepository/resource/img/loading.gif') center no-repeat #fff;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes @ obuliraj. In the first answer Andrew told me, I misunderstood it and put it there. I just edited that and pushed the update on my testing server. My other squestion still same to both you and Girish and EaziLuizi that Is it ethical to display a pre-loader on page unload or Can I ?  I mean does this perform the task of displaying a preloader between page loads

Answer (score 0):

```
/* page Loader dynamically call */
/* for particular div and all page */
/*html*/
 <div id="divLoaderContainer">
        <!--Lodar for body start-->
        <div class="preLoaderPage nodisplay">
            <img class="loading-image" src="~/Content/Images/preLoader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
        </div>
        <!--Lodar for body end-->
        <!--Lodar for div start-->
        <div class="preLoaderDiv nodisplay">
            <img class="loading-image" src="~/Content/Images/preLoader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
        </div>
        <!--Lodar for div end-->
    </div>
/*css*/
.preLoaderPage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: #dae3ec;
    z-index: 99;
}
.preLoaderDiv {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.94);
    z-index: 99;
}

.preLoaderPage .loading-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 100;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
}
.preLoaderDiv .loading-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 100;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
/*Loader here end*/
/*JS function*/
// for full loader
function showLoader(id) {
    if (id == null || id == undefined || id == '') {
        $("div.preLoaderPage").removeClass('nodisplay');
    }
    else {
        showPartialLoader(id)
    }
}
function hideLoader(id) {
    if (id == null || id == undefined || id == '') {
        $("div.preLoaderPage").addClass('nodisplay');
    }
    else {
        hidePartialLoader(id)
    }
}
// for specific div loader

function showPartialLoader(id) {
    var loaderdiv = $("#divLoaderContainer div.preLoaderDiv").clone();
    $(loaderdiv).removeClass('nodisplay');
    var content = $("div#" + id).closest('div.x_content');
    if (content.length > 0)
        $("div#" + id).closest('div.x_content').append(loaderdiv);
    else {
        $("div#" + id).append(loaderdiv);
    }
}

function hidePartialLoader(id) {
    var content = $("div#" + id).closest('div.x_content');
    if (content.length > 0)
        $("div#" + id).closest('div.x_content').find('div.preLoaderDiv').remove();
    else
        $("div#" + id + ' div.preLoaderDiv').remove();
}


/*call by JS*/

$.ajax({
           showLoader(id);// id of div or container

            success: function (data) {
               // your code
            },
hideLoader(id)// id of above div or container
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.se-pre-con {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('http://www.rybena.com.br:8080/RybenaRepository/resource/img/loading.gif') center no-repeat #fff;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.